# Is the definition of aVF consistent with Novosel’s formula?

Tags: heart-disease, heart, electrocardiogram, heartbeat

"In regards to the electrocardiogram, there is often a Statement made that,

**'The a' in aVF means 'augmented' by a factor of 1.5 for sensitivity adjustment.**

If the above statement  is true, following equation should be true.

$VF = aVF/1.5$
[image]

Here, $VF$ represents the **original voltage** in the VF direction, VI represents lead I.

If the above Statement is correct, the argument of Heart vector, $\theta$ should be

$\theta = \arctan \left(\frac{VF}{V_I}\right)
= arctan\left(\frac{2 VF}{ 3 V_I}\right)$
[image]

However, the correct formula by Novosel is as follows, as described below in the British Physiological Society's resource intended to "Beginner" level Medical School students .
https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/

$\theta = arctan \left(\frac{2 VF}{\sqrt{3} VI}\right)$
[image]

and my own calculations also lead to the same conclusion.

Therefore, in order to align with this formula:

$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\frac{aVF}{VI} = \frac{VF}{VI}$
[image]

It follows that:

$aVF = \frac{aVF}{2 VF} \approx 0.85 VF$
[image]

Hence, aVF seems to be smaller than VF.

My question;

> So the Statement that **aVF is 1.5 times the true voltage of VF seems to contradict Novosel's formula.**　What do you think?

After several hours of study　after post this question, I actually understood the answer. As a result, I realized that this question can be chunked down to the following question, which can probably be answered by anyone who understands the beginner's course in EKG.

- What is aVF and where is the potential difference?
- What is aVF 1.5x?
- How does the Vectorcardiogram relate to aVF?

References;

- https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/
- https://www.bem.fi/book/15/15.htm
  Written in Japanese
- [http://www.hoku-iryo-u.ac.jp/~kurahasi/kurahasi/103.3.pdf](http://www.hoku-iryo-u.ac.jp/%7Ekurahasi/kurahasi/103.3.pdf)
- https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11285430786
- https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11285430786

Comment: The Tex command for describing mathematical expressions is not properly converted into mathematical expressions. Can someone help me?

Comment: MathJax isn't enabled on this site. Anyway why did you put quotes around your question? Is this copy paste from a different place?

Comment: Thanks for the info. The quote is a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Also, looks like you're in the wrong site. This site is for medical questions, not for math questions. I see you also have account on the Math site so easy to get confused.

Comment: I have never learned about EKG in my math classes. Is the measurement of ECG taught in math class in your country?

Comment: The question is about math equations. It's not about EKG. I'm not a mod, and didn't even vote to close because there's no fitting close reason, just saying that you're probably not going to get answer here.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the other questions, I get the impression that many of them are more like health counseling offices than medical ones.

If this is some sort of health counseling office for the layman, then you are correct in your assertion, but I understand that physiology as the basis of medicine as taught in the medical community, i.e., circulatory physiology in medical school, is included in the community's subject matter?


I believe that the method of determining the mean electrical axis from an ECG is a matter of medicine, although it does indeed use mathematics.

Comment: Any way,　at least this question is based on the British Physiological Society (not the British Mathematical Society) article I cited, which, if I am not mistaken, clearly states that the article is about basic education on ECG. https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But it's like asking on Cooking.SE site a question like "What formula to use to cook meat in the best way?" asking for math formula. It's related to cooking, yes, but only math experts can answer, and they're not likely to roam that site. Same here.

Comment: Health counseling questions are off topic here and closed immediately. The only such questions of that nature you should find are probably years old.

Comment: I don't see any problem with asking the question here.

Comment: If you are quoting from a specific source, you should identify that source alongside the quote so it's clear where it came from

Comment: Indeed, this was actually a very easy problem if one understood the rudiments of ECGs. After all, this was an exercise for a beginner's course at a medical school. If you don't understand this, you probably don't understand ECG at all. That's true.

Comment: It is very hard to say, but it seems that probably no one here has completed a beginner's course in EKG.

Comment: All this can be said from these two references.　One seems to be a beginner's material from a British medical school and the other from a Finnish medical school. https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/
https://www.bem.fi/book/15/15.htm

Comment: If I may make a suggestion to myself,10 hours ago; look at the second reference below. That explains why it is 1.5x. It has nothing to do with finding the declination from the aVF, just with understanding the circuit configuration of two typical ECG measurements and using your middle school science knowledge. Even if you don't know that, the second literature has the answer.　That's all.

Comment: I am a beginner as you all are when it comes to EKG and have made some progress in the last 10 hours, although very little. On the other hand, this community will always remain in beta. I think I understand why. Medical school courses in basic medicine use molecular biology, mathematics, and even physics; the definition of aVF is not a mathematical subject. The level of this community will probably remain the same, just as medical school education is not viable if it excludes questions that use the language of other disciplines.

Comment: If you don't understand this , what do you know about the ECG? aVF is the difference in potential between where and where? aVF is 1.5x to what? vectorcardiogram is related to aVF?
If you can explain it exactly without using formulas, do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To myself 10 hours ago, stumbling through the most rudimentary cardiology course in medical school.

You are confusing two issues.

- The first is the definition of aVF and VF and its relationship to I~III induction.
- The second is the relationship between Heart vector and aVF

These are independent concepts. Your question is about how the medical community defined aVF, VF, and Heart vector, and many mathematicians may not even know that such a vector exists, since there is no such vector in mathematics. So the best person to ask your question would be someone who has completed at least a beginner's course in EKG, but unfortunately I have just started working on one of the earlier courses.

First of all, there are two elementary circuit configurations for ECG measurement systems: the Wilson and Goldberger formulas. The Wilson equation measures VL VR and VF, while the Goldberger equation measures aVR, aVF, and aVL. This fact is carefully explained in an excellent learning resource for medical school beginners;
https://www.bem.fi/book/15/15.htm

To summarize the important points,
[image]
and
[image]

> The source of the "1.5x" in your question is this.

On the other hand, the second issue, t**he relation between aVF and Heart vector**, is as described in the excellent resource you cited that the British Physiological Society (not the British Mathematical Society) has provided for medical school beginners;
https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/

However, this resource does not clearly define aVF or I induction. That may have been a bit unkind to someone like you 10 hours ago, who doesn't associate 1.5x and aVF with the above, and who doesn't understand the basics of ECGs at all. But you already know, don't you, that **the definitions of aVF and I induction are the same as what was written in the literature earlier**?

Ok, First, in the vectorcardiogram, we consider that Heart Vector \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{t}) changes from time to time and its projection to each induction direction is induction I, II, and III. In other words, we have first

[image]

To answer your question, we don't need to talk about something as advanced as the variation of the heart vector over time. So let's fix time t. Then, If we think of it in the same way as the common 6-axis coordinate system diagram, we will see that;

[image]

Then, eliminating the term cos from equations (1-2-II) and (1-2-III), we obtain

[image]

and further by considering Eindt-Haen's equation in (1-6), we obtain
[image]

Here, Ⅱ+Ⅲ=2aVF　
Then,

[image]

This is the Novocel's formula you mentioned and described in following article you sited.
https://www.physoc.org/magazine-articles/trigonometry-of-the-ecg/

Summing up all the discussion so far, we get the following equation.
[image]

So, to emphasize again,

> Hy is not equal to either VF or aVF.

Therefore, although the current ECG equipment outputs aVF and I induction,

> when you want to find the heart vector, it is perfectly OK to plot I induction in the x direction, but you should not write aVF or VF in the aVF direction.

- **If you really want to use aVF to obtain ECG vector, you must multiply the value of aVF by 1.16, and **
- **If you really want to use VF to obtain ECG vector, you musts multiply the value of VF by 1.73, and **